# Autostart works on login but not on first boot

Tags: lubuntu, autostart

I have tried several things.

- Desktop Entry in `/usr/share/applications`
- Desktop Entry in `~/.config/autostart`
- Adding script to `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`
- Creating a startup.sh to run instead of the executable for the application

All of these work when I boot up > logout > login.  But none of them work on the first boot.

I am running Lubuntu 14.04

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with autostart ? X is not running when you boot so you need to autostart graphical apps at login.

Comment: There is an application I want to autostart on login.  The problem is that it does not work on the first login.  After I logout and then back in the program runs.  Also it is set to autologin using `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

Comment: Just stating it is not working is not much help. What application ? What is in your script ?

Comment: The application I am trying to run is and [Augmented Reality Sandbox](http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/ResDev/SARndbox/).  I have tried to above methods to run the program but it only works after I have logged in once.  The scripts I wrote were just simple bash scripts to run the application command.  I think the program is trying to run before the Kinect is loaded which causes it to fail and may be the reason it works after a logout and login.

Comment: So add a sleep 10 or 15 to the script

Comment: @bodhi.zazen this is a little old now but just to let you know a different distro and sleep 5 fixed the problem.  Thanks for your help